# My pseudo element overlay isn't working

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to put an image (or even just a simple rgba color) overlay on top of a bootstrap background slider. I've never had trouble getting this particular effect to work on other websites, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It's a WordPress site, but so are all the others I've done this with.

```css
section.top-carousel {
  height: 65em;
}

#background-carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -10px;
}

#background-carousel .carousel,
#background-carousel .carousel-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#background-carousel .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 65em;
}

div#background-carousel:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 65em;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-carousel">
  <div id="background-carousel">
    <div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        ...slides are in here, generated by a WP loop...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've tried that last set of styling in various places: as #top-carousel:before & :after, for #homeCarousel:before & after, .carousel.slide:before & after, and even on .carousel-inner:before & after. This is just the latest one I tried before I kind of gave up and came here. Since I've got a position of "Relative" on the #background-carousel, I would think that the position of "Absolute" on the pseudo element would take care of things. But clearly it's not. I must be over-tired not to be able to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add content to the psuedo element

```
div#background-carousel:before {
content:'';
}
```

Comment: Oy vey. See? I *knew* it was going to be something dumb I'd missed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

without the `content` property, which is part of the generated `content` module in the specification, pseudo-elements are useless. So, while the pseudo-element selector itself is needed to target the element, you won’t be able to insert anything without adding the content property. Use content it will be work fine.

Example on jsFiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/xa1jq7op/